# Including several Maps from GoogleMaps API without callback

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gwt, jsni

I've been wondering about a way to include a random number of maps in a web page. I'm currently working with GWT and embedding my javascript code into a JSNI function. I have an array of maps but due to my architecture, every map does know nothing about the others. My problem is that I have to include the gmaps script this way (asynchronously):

```
var script = $doc.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&initializeMaps";
$doc.body.appendChild(script);
```

The issue here is that I don't know the ids of the maps when loading the script, so I cannot load all of them within the 'initializeMaps' function.

I would like to know whether it is possible to load each map separately instead of depending on the 'initializeMaps' callback, where as I have said, I don't know the maps ids yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days I've figured out about how to do it. I thought that loading the Gmaps script at first with no callback wasn't correct and I still don't know, althought I did it.

I included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

within the head of my document and then I initialized every map with the same function to which I provided map ids as input. As you can see the parameter "initializeMaps" which I was using as callback is not placed in the GMaps url anymore.

The problem is that I have to carry that included script in some places where I don't need it. I don't know whether this is a right approach to the use of GoogleMaps API, but it has been impossible to do it for me without this workaround.